# 4 cores missing and high load after upgrade from 14.10 to 16.04.1

Tags: server, upgrade, htop

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu Server from 14.10 to 16.04.1. It's running a core i7 with HT which is clearly enabled in the BIOS (see Photos)

[image]

[image]

However, htop shows only 4 virtual cores (before the update there were 8) as well as an average load of something above ~4. It seems like something is hiding 4 virtual cores and using them constantly. When running htop as root there is nothing to be seen that uses 400% CPU load.

[image]

How can I check what's going on and get my 4 cores back?

Edit:

```
:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 30
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x5
cpu MHz     : 2933.232
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5866.46
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 30
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x5
cpu MHz     : 2933.232
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5866.46
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 30
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x5
cpu MHz     : 2933.232
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5866.46
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 30
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x5
cpu MHz     : 2933.232
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5866.46
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: The load doesn't tell you how many CPU cores are being used. Please paste (not a screenshot) the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` into the question, select it, and click on the `{}` button in the editor to properly format it.

Comment: Can you edit the post to include to output of cat /proc/cpuinfo. I do not know what is causing htop to behave that way.

Comment: Added  cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: Do you boot with the option `acpi=off`? If you're not sure, check `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was to enable acpi for the OS in the BIOS. There is a setting to enable for ACPI aware operating systems. 
I switched it off before the upgrade to be able to boot from a live USB Stick and make a back up. Totally forgot about it until I read Chai T.Rex's answer.
Thanks everyone!